# Adding admin subdomain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hosting, subdomain

I have a website that i am hosting from home. I want to add a subdomain to my website, for example: admin.mywebsite.com Would it be best to create a new project and point DNS to that project, or should i rather create the admin application in a folder under the current project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'best' option, certainly not one which is best in all circumstances.

Personally, I would have the admin bundled in with the main site as it will help you synchronise changes to your data access in your web application with changes in your admin system. When you deploy new versions, you know you are deploying an admin site and main site that work together. When you have two, you have two projects to maintain, two to deploy and you might find sharing code between the two a pain.

You may wish to keep the sites partitioned more strictly though so perhaps two sites is best for you. If you haven't got a compelling reason to have the separated, then don't otherwise you lose the benefits above.